# Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler

Tags: asp.net, profiling, eqatec

I'm searching for a free ASP.NET profiler, and I stumbled upon [EQATEC Profiler for .NET](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler), but I can't find any instructions on how to profile ASP.NET projects with it. Please post step-by-step instructions or a link with sufficient info.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional and .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It looks like they have changed their user interface since Pavel's instructions were posted. Here are the instructions I wrote up for my team. They replace steps 4-8 in Pavel's post.

To profile an ASP.NET application using EQATEC, just select the application’s bin folder in the App Path setting.

Then, click the Build button at the bottom of the form.

Then, load your app and go to the page you want to profile. Go to the Run tab and click the Reset Counters button.

Then, do the action that you want to profile. When it’s done, click the Take Snapshot button.

When that is done, a snapshot report will appear in the bottom list. You can double-click on it to view it.

Answer (score 44):

This should work for ASP.NET web projects:

1. Compile your project.
2. Start web application. You can right-click on some .aspx file in Visual Studio and select "View in Browser". (If you start your application later you risk overwriting profiled DLL.)
3. Start EQATEC Profiler.
4. On the Build tab browse to bin folder of your project.
5. Click “App options” button

   - Set output folder to $(AppDir) only.
   - Uncheck “Ordinary app”.
6. Click Build button.
7. Switch to your favourite browser. Navigate to the page you want to profile. You should get "Profiled app started" entry in Run tab in EQATEC Profiler.
8. Click "Take snapshot" button. A new entry should appear in "View snapshot reports" list. Select it and click View button.

Edit: Updated instructions according to comment.

Comment: An update from the EQATEC forums: http://www.eqatec.com/forum/profiler/bugs-problems/293776181/conversation_view?b_start:int=7&-C=
I will add two things to both their instructions:

0) First of all, read their instructions. Then in App Option do this:
1) Unmark "Ordinary app". This will prevent the warning about a missing Main-method.
2) Set output folder to $(AppDir) only. This will write the profiled DLLs directly into the bin-folder instead of bin-Profiled, saving you to do the manual copying yourself.

Comment: They changed the user interface in their new release. See my answer below for new screenshots.

Answer (score 7):

From the EQATEC forums:

- [ASP.NET?](http://www.eqatec.com/forum/profiler/bugs-problems/905006992/#903912541)
- [tracing asp.net web application](http://www.eqatec.com/forum/tracer/general-discussion/587914964/#42616725)
- [Profiling web application](http://www.eqatec.com/forum/profiler/bugs-problems/350359133/#789976522)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to get a compiled version of your site (is there a dll for the site in the bin folder or just the dependencies?). 
The easiest way to do this is to publish it. (Just right hand click the site in Visual Studio). Then Pavel's answer will work just fine.