# EQATEC Profiler - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: asp.net, profiling, eqatec

I'm trying to use EQATEC Profiler to profile my ASP.Net app.  I followed the instructions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler).  It worked the first time, but every since then, when I run my app, I don't get a "Profiled app started" message.  Then when I click on the "Take snapshot" button, I get the following:

"Taking snapshot ...failed: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Why can't it find my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I should provide an update on this.  The error was resolved once I downloaded the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If a profiled app encounters errors it will log these to the profiler.log file. By default you will find this in C:\Windows\Temp\EQATECProfilerLogs. Try to see if it holds some clues. You can also try to enable "Full logging" in the app options, which will at least output something to the log.

A profiled app is actually the "server" when talking to the profiler; it is the profiler that connects to the app, not the other way around. In your case it seems that the old app has stopped listening (otherwise the profiler's attempt to connect would simply be served by the old app), but the new app has not (could not?) started listening.

It seems strange, though, so my best suggestion is to examine the log-file. It will e.g. show if the app could not start its control-server and if so, why not.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try rebuilding (in Equatec) your application.  Make sure "enable runtime control" is enabled in the application options when you build.

1a) Try changing the port being used for runtime control.

2) Run your application through Equatec

3) Check if you have anything funny for firewall settings or similar.  Some firewalls treat Equatec communication as traffic to be blocked.

4.  If all else fails, just close your application normally.  Even if taking snapshots fails, you can still see the profile once your application is closed.