# How to build a tracing log in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there an easy way to generate a log file that will trace at runtime the path through the code? I would like to see every controller, action, and view that was executed as my program runs.

Can this be done without having to add logging code to every controller, action, and view?

Comment: Why not just use a profiler tool? There's one built into Visual Studio, and there are several other alternatives like the ones from RedGate and JetBrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Equatec Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler/937493#937493

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the actual execution path then try [EQATEC Tracer](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/tracer) - it does pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

You don't need to change your source at all: the tracer injects "tracing-code" into your compiled application which will at runtime tell you exactly what methods are executed and what the parameters are.