# Is there an Open Source Profiler for .Net 4?

Tags: .net, performance, .net-4.0

Is there an Open Source Profiler for .Net 4? RedGate Antz is an option but I am looking for an open source alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not open-source, but free for personal use: [Eqatec Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler)

Comment: Does it support profiling of an Asp.Net application

Comment: Yes: Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler

Comment: Just an update - Eqatec was acquired by Teleric and  being phased out in favor of their own tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Slim Tune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/) is "a free profiler and performance analysis/tuning tool for .NET based applications", MIT licensed and supports .Net 4.0 (as of the 0.3.0 release of Feb 12th 2011).

Comment: just FYI if you're hitting this, slimtune has not been updated since version 0.3.0 (feb 2011)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of [NProfiler](https://web.archive.org/web/20090205014114/http://chimpswithkeyboards.com/projects/nprofiler/) (GPL, [SourceForge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nprofiler/)), but I have never used it. Sorry.