# Eqatec profiler-reset counter and take snapshot buttons disabled

Tags: eqatec

I'm trying to use EQATEC Profiler to profile my ASP.Net app. I am following the below steps to do it. I have selected the application's bin folder in App path and clicked on the build button. Then I have run the application from visual studio 2005. However, i don't see the reset counter or take snapshot buttons enabled. Please help.

Comment: I have noticed an error in the eventlogs. I have set the output folder to $(AppDir) in App Options. Due to this the newly generated dll's are getting craeted in the bin. The application is getting restarted:Global.asax|Application_End()|Inside of Application_End() : shutDownMessage  :Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a nice step-by-step instruction and explanation in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler).

I may also have an explanation of what's going wrong for you:

1. You compile your asp.net app in VS2005 - fine
2. You then instrument and overwrite your app using Build in the profiler - also fine
3. But then you run your app *from VS2005* and that may re-compile your app again so you're running an un-instrumented version. Instead of running it from VS2005 you should simply have IIS "launch" the code by navigating to the corresponding webpage.

If this is not the problem then take a look at the log-file generated by the running, profiled app. By default the log-file is located in `C:\Windows\Temp\EQATECProfilerLogs\profiler.log`.