# Freeware asp.net profiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling

I cam currentlyt using [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CO6fmJPNrqQCFQ25bwod00WszQ) Anyone knows of a free solution?

Thanks

Luis

Comment: Any .NET profiler will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler) is free and used by quite many developers. It doesn't have direct support for ASP.NET, though, but needs a few extra manual steps as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler).

Answer (score 1):

[CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) is a great tool and pretty simple to use.  It was created by the guys here at StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried SO many profilers for asp.net - ANTS is good but expensive, EQATEC seemed good, but ruddy complicated and makes finding what I actually wanted to know really hard.  I'd like to give a vote for [Drone Profiler](http://www.droneprofiler.com/index.aspx) - really simple to setup, supports asp.net well, and gives information that I actually want to know!

Comment: Sadly, Drone appears to be dead now. The website you link to says "The DRONE profiler is no more".