# How can I profile an ASP.NET application running on a production server?

Tags: asp.net, profiling

I have an ASP.NET application that is consistently using 75% - 100% of the CPU on a production server.  How can I profile the application to figure out what part of the code is using up the most CPU?  I have looked at a couple of different tools (Xte Profiler, EQATEC, dotTrace), but they all seem to want you to load and run the application within their tool.  It seems to me that they want you to load up the application in their tool and run tests locally (not in production).  I want to profile the application while it is running in production with people hitting it to see what is actually going on.  Is this possible?

I am a newbie to application profiling so forgive me if I have missed something obvious or am not thinking about this correctly.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet is to profile your code on your own machine to identify where it is spending time.

Grab a ten day free trial of this:

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Here are some links to get you going:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108150604/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alikl/archive/2009/03/06/why-my-asp-net-application-s-performance-is-less-than-optimal.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178643(v=VS.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx

Comment: It's better to create a staging environment duplicating the production and test there

Comment: I agree. However, it is also okay to test for bottlenecks on your development machine as long as you are careful.

Comment: I don't agree. One can duplicate environment in a staging environment, but one cannot duplicate behaviour. A site can behave differenttly when receiving 10 requests from receiving 100 requests at once. For example, I have a site that receives requests from biometric devices in time attendance systems I developed. When I test the system in development machine or a staging machine, it works like a charm, but when it received requests from several devices at once, I have problems. In order to simulate the real behaviour of people and the devices it would be almost a new project,

Answer (score 8):

Sam Saffron (one of the StackoverFlow creators) has written a great command-line tool a while ago, but unfortunately has abandoned it.

A friend of mine forked the code to make it work in 2015:

https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer

(the page has a link to Sam's post explaining how to use it)

The great thing about this tool (besides "no-install required" portability, cmd-line interface, etc etc) is that APM packages like NewRelic etc only monitor http-requests. If your app has some background threads - they won't help much.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider taking a memory dump on the production server while it's experiencing high CPU. Check out [ADPlus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-windows-startup) and taking a hang dump on the asp.net process.  This can then be analyzed with [Windbg](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) or other tools.

I just went through a similar experience where our production servers were experiencing excessive CPU load - a scenario we could not recreate locally or in test/staging environments. It had nothing to do with the database (database CPU was normal).  Analyzing the dump file is what clued us in on what was causing the problem (excessive compilation of regex objects by some library we were using).

This answer would be incomplete without [Tess' blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/), so here's the link.

Comment: Hmmm..Yes, we did that yesterday.  But I had no idea how to analyze it.  Maybe I just need to really learn more about ADPlus and Windbg, because I really felt like I didn't know exactly what I was doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it has to do with long running database queries rather than the ASP.net application itself. In my experience 9 times out of 10 this is what I see and this takes the APPLICATION server down to a crawl as resources are consumed and the app has to wait for each query to finish to move on. Take a look at SQL profilier on the DB server and see if there are any queries that are taking a long time to execute.

It could be as simple as adding an index to a column or some other small minor optimizations. Once you know the query, you can then also go back to your code and tweak that section as well.

Comment: Well, the SQL Server machine is barely doing anything.  The RAM and the CPU and the overall performance of the database server is fine.  So I am thinking that it is not a DB problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question still, it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If a server is running that high on CPU, odds are, a standard profiler will bring it to a grinding halt due to it's additional overhead.

There are actually three different types of profilers. Standard profilers, lightweight transaction profilers, and APM tools. You can read more about this in my blog post that discusses all 3:

[.NET Profilers: 3 types and why you need all of them](https://stackify.com/three-types-of-net-profilers/)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to profile ASP.NET with the EQATEC Profiler. See:
[Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler)

EQATEC Profiler instruments your app in a separate step that enable the app itself to collect it's own profiling info, and the profiler then merely displays that timing data afterwards.

That means that you can run your instrumented ASP.NET app completely independent of the profiler itself.
You could e.g. instrument your app, mail it to your test site in India, have them run it on their server for some days where it will generate timing reports all on it's own, and have them mail back those reports to you, which you can then view in the profiler. Pretty neat.

Note: To have the profiled app generate timing snapshots "on it's own" it must know when to generate them. By default this is when the method Application_End is called in an ASP.NET app. You can programmatically dump snapshots when it suits you by using the EQATEC Profiler API. See the user guide or check out [this thread](http://forum.eqatec.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=341).

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this on Microsoft Developer Network.
You can select documentation according to the version of your Visual Studio. You should verify profiling functionality is provided for your Visual Studio type.

[How to: Profile a Web Site or Web Application Using the Performance Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d(v=vs.100).aspx)