# asp.net page takes long load time on server

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have got a .aspx page 
When I run it on localhost it get executed with approx 17 sec.
Following is the screenshot of network tab of browser

[image]

The same page when I upload it on server and try to run it it takes approx 2 minutes which is too long
Following is the screen shot

[image]

I have made changes to the web.config file as compilation debug="true" 
along with enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" also made changes in the view state.

My database is on the other domain and the .aspx page is on another domain. I also tried uploading the page on the same domain and run it but it is also slow. Please Help.

Comment: Check how much response takes to reach you after sent from server. It it is transport then your connection might be slow or data is large. It it is not transport then check what part of process is taking time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I profile an ASP.NET application running on a production server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978566/how-can-i-profile-an-asp-net-application-running-on-a-production-server)

Comment: There really is no way for others to answer this, you'll need to [go profile your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978566/how-can-i-profile-an-asp-net-application-running-on-a-production-server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a tracer and found that the user controls takes long load time . Fixed it. Thanks @CodeCaster and @Adil

Comment: sir what did u do about user control ?